# Pass a structure's content to another variable in C

Tags: c

I have this code for now:

```
pacient sortClients(int n, pacient *lista, int print)
{
    pacient aux[50];  

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    *(aux+i)=*(lista+i);

    //some modifications performed on aux

    return *aux;
}

void sortAndShowByAge(int n, pacient *lista)
{
   pacient aux[50];
   *aux=sortClients(n,lista,0);

}
```

The last function is where I get in trouble. If aux has only one record then it works ok, if there are more than two, it shows some weird characters. In the first function I iterated over lista and saved every record to aux. Is there a way to assign the aux from sortClients to aux in shortAndShowByAge directly and not iterate? I can't iterate over sortClients.

Comment: Please post actual code. This snippet doesn't even compile and the display logic is not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code simply returns a single element, rather than the entire array. It can't legally return the array as written, since it's a local variable.

You need to either allocate new memory dynamically, or sort in-place.

The former, which is most like what you have already, would go like this:

```
pacient * sortClients(int n, const pacient *lista, int print)
{
    pacient *aux;

    if((aux = malloc(n * sizeof *aux)) != NULL)
    {
      memcpy(aux, lista, n * sizeof *aux);
      /*some modifications performed on aux */
    }
    return aux;
}
```

This returns a pointer to the sorted/processed array, which you must call `free()` on when you're done with, in order not to leak memory.

I alao corrected the return type, and use `memcpy()` instead of a manual loop to copy the input values. The input array is marked as `const` too, since it's read-only for the function.

Comment: The original code does not return a pointer to local, it just returns a single array element by value.Though I think the intention of OP was to return an pointer to the local array, which would be an UB.

Comment: @unwind thank you, it works perfectly. It's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that:

```
 pacient sortClients(int n, pacient *lista, int print)
```

returns **one** instance of `pacient`. It doesn't return an array:

```
 return *aux; /* <---- synonymous with return aux[0]; */
```

In `sortAndShowByAge()`, the following takes the single element that's been returned and copies it into `aux[0]`:

```
 *aux=sortClients(n,lista,0); /* <---- synonymous with aux[0]=... */
```

I think the best way to fix this would simply have `sortClients()` modify the supplied array in place, and not have to return anything. That'll fix the bug and will get rid of much of the unnecessary copying.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the pointer to `aux` as a parameter to a function instead. Also, you can use memcpy instead of a loop (unless you do those modifications in the loop):

```
void sortClients(int n, pacient *lista, pacient *aux, int print)
{
    memcpy(aux, lista, n * sizeof(pacient));

    //some modifications performed on aux
}

void sortAndShowByAge(int n, pacient *lista)
{
   pacient aux[50];
   sortClients(n,lista,aux,0);

}
```

You can, of course, use the for loop you already have. The key is that aux is created in the caller, and you pass the pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function does not return valid content because aux is declared locally in the function.

Instead you could declare a structure with the array inside it and return that to get a copy

```
typedef struct ret
{
   pacient aux[50];
} ret_t;

...

ret_t sortClients( int n, pacient *lista, int print ) {...}
```

or you allocate the array using malloc in your function and return the address of that memory block

```
pacient* sortClients(...)

pacient *aux = malloc(50 * sizeof( pacient ) );
...

return aux;
```